# Creating a Copy Constructor/function for a linked list in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a copy function for linked lists (called OLList) which contain a structure called Node. Node has an integer (renamed ListItem) called item, and a pointer of type Node called Next.

I am getting strange results. Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Here a simple class for the linked list without getters/setters

```cpp
struct Node {
  ListItem item;
  Node *next;
};

class OLList {
private:
  Node *headM;
};
```

here is the function

```cpp
void OLList::copy(const OLList& source)
{    
    if(source.headM==0)
        return;

    Node *after=source.headM->next;
    Node *temp=new Node;
    int *data_1=new ListItem;
    if(temp==NULL || data_1==NULL)
        exit(1);

    data_1=&source.headM->item;
    temp->item=*data_1;

    Node *ret=temp;

    while(after!=0){
        temp=temp->next;
        temp=new Node;
        int *data=new ListItem;

        if(temp==NULL || data==NULL)
            exit(1);

        data=&after->item;
        temp->item=*data;

        after=after->next;
    }   
    temp->next=0;   
    headM=ret;
    delete temp;
}
```

I have a control link list called the_list:

[ 99, 110, 120, 220, 330, 440, 550 ]

and I copy the linked list TWICE in two different ways. I should mention that this function is called by the assignment operator.

```cpp
OLList other_list;
other_list = the_list;

OLList third_list = the_list;
```

The assignment operator (cannot be changed, b/c it was assigned to me):

```cpp
OLList& OLList::operator =(const OLList& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs) {
        destroy();  //this is to prevent self copy
        copy(rhs);  //function is called here
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I get the following outputs respectively:

```cpp
testing for copying lists ...
other_list as a copy of the_list: expected to be [ 99, 110, 120, 220, 330, 440, 550 ]
[ 99 ]
third_list as a copy of the_list: expected to be: [ 99, 110, 120, 220, 330, 440, 550 ]
[ 99, -2144292712, -2144292728, -2144292744, -2144292760, 0 ]
```

so the first one copies just the first element, and the second one copies who knows what...
I am still new to programming so please ELI5! Thank you.

Comment: `if(source.headM==0) return;` after copying from an empty list I would expect that both are empty. Anyhow, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that line is checking to make sure the SOURCE is not pointing to NULL.

Comment: `source` is a reference, it cannot point to NULL, and again: If i copy from a list that has nothing inside, I would expect that afterwards both lists contain the same

Comment: Im confused. In the code you provided `copy` is never called.

Comment: @TomBombadil It is a function called by a copy constructor

Comment: If you want to call the copy contructor it should be something like `OLList other_list(the_list)` Right now you are calling `OLList::operator=(OLList &other)`

Comment: @TomBombadil i added the copy constructor to the code above. Everything except the function copy was provided to me, ie the copy constructor.

Comment: That is an assignment operator, not a copy constructor (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor vs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment)

Comment: @TomBombadil my bad, yes youre right.

Comment: @TomBombadil changes are reflected

Comment: It looks like you're not calling `copy` from the copy constructor (only the copy assignment operator). Can you show us the copy constructor to confirm? `other_list = the_list;` calls the copy assignment operator and `OLList third_list = the_list;` calls the copy constructor.

Comment: @Kerndog73 the assignment operator is called copy constructor by John

Comment: @TomBombadil A copy assignment operator and a copy constructor are **two different things**. [This is a copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) and [this is a copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: @Kerndog73 I know. Please read the comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code has several problems:

```
int *data_1=new ListItem; // here you allocate a ListItem (strange, why you store it in a int* ?)
// ...
data_1=&source.headM->item; // and a couple of LoC you replace it with another pointer; thats a memory leak
temp->item = *data_1; // overcomplicated way to copy
```

Maybe you wanted just to copy the value?

```
temp->item = source.head->item; // we can throw that data_1 ptr out
```

The same situation with `int * data`.

Another strange moment:

```
temp=temp->next;
temp=new Node;
```

Two assignments in a row without using the first value is an indication of an error. Here you store the `next` pointer to `temp`, but immediately rewrite it with another allocated `Node`, so your first node, `ret`, never gets a valid `next` pointer value.

```
void OLList::copy(const OLList& source)
{    
    if(source.headM==nullptr) // using 0 for indicating empty pointer is bad!
        return;

    Node *after=source.headM->next;
    Node *temp=new Node;
    if(temp==NULL)
        exit(1);

    temp->item=source.headM->item; // just copy the value;

    headM=temp; // store the first node

    while(after!=nullptr){
        temp->next=new Node; // create the next node
        if(temp->next==NULL)
            exit(1);

        temp=temp->next; // move to next node
        temp->item=after->item; // copy the value
        after=after->next; // update after ptr
    }
    temp->next=0; // indicate, that that's the last one
    // don't delete temp, because it is added to list;
}
```

However, you can simplify even more (from some perspective) with pointers to pointers:

```
void OLList::copy(const OLList& source) {
    Node ** tmp = &headM; // we'll put the nodes with this ptr
    Node * toCopy = source.headM;
    while (toCopy != nullptr) {
        Node * node = new Node; // create new node
        if (node == nullptr)
            exit(1);

        *tmp = node; // put the node to its place (headM at first, then next member of prev node)
        node->item = toCopy->item; // copy the value
        toCopy = toCopy->next;
        tmp = &(node->next); // update where we'll put the next node
    }
    *tmp = nullptr; // that was the last one
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!